# Embed An External Website In A Wordpress.com Page

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to embed an external website inside a **Wordpress.com** website page? When I try to use `<iframe>`s or `[iframe]`s, Wordpress seems to trim the tags and we are left with the hyperlink only.

If not, does **WordPress.com Business Plan** cover this feature?

An example is [this page](http://orebropadelcenter.se/boka/) where the entire *Matchi* content comes live from an external page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress.com does not allow this, ref: https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/

> Flash and other types of embed that use; frame, iframe, form, input, object, textarea are not allowed in WordPress.com posts, pages, or text widgets on the Premium Plan and below.

Comment: Thank you! Then I assume even the Premium Plan does not cover them and one should go with the Business Plan. I think I got my answer.

Comment: Glad to help. Correct, from the page: "The code limitations mentioned above apply only to the Free, Personal, and Premium Plans."